# Get data contents of iCloud URL without UIDocument

Tags: ios, objective-c, icloud

Is it possible to get the contents of an iCloud URL without having to go through UIDocument?

Comment: Short answer: yes. Long answer: I can't provide the code right now, but I did it a while ago. You may want to search Apples Documentation for "Ubiquity Container".

Answer (score 1):

You can use the following code for downloding the contents of icloud url without creating the object of NSDocument. This will be worked for me...

```
-(void)loadData:(NSMetadataQuery *)query
{
    if ([query resultCount] == 1)
    {
        NSMetadataItem *item = [query resultAtIndex:0];
        NSURL *fromURL = [item valueForAttribute:NSMetadataItemURLKey];
        NSURL *toURL=[NSURL fileURLWithPath:@"PATH_OF_FILE_TO_STORE_DATA"];

        NSFileCoordinator *coordinator = [[NSFileCoordinator alloc] initWithFilePresenter:nil];

        [coordinator coordinateReadingItemAtURL:fromURL options:0 writingItemAtURL:toURL options:NSFileCoordinatorWritingForReplacing error:nil byAccessor:^(NSURL *newReadingURL, NSURL *newWritingURL)
         {
             [[NSFileManager defaultManager] removeItemAtPath:newWritingURL.path error:NULL];
             [[NSFileManager defaultManager] copyItemAtPath:newReadingURL.path toPath:newWritingURL.path error:nil];
       }];
    }
}
```